# Force render component 1 when i refresh component 2

Tags: reactjs

I made a blog project in React. The array of objects (articles) are loaded from component 1. When i click the article title in component 1, and going on component 2 (entire article) everything is rendered ok. If i hit refresh, is rendered just component 2 and component 1 no, so i get TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.

If i go back in component 1, everything is rendered and i can access again component 2. I use router dom.

How can i force render component 1 when i refresh component 2?

Here is my component 2:

```
render(){
    return (

        <div className="SinglePageContainer">
            <div className="SinglePageTitle">{this.props.currentObject.title}</div>
            <div className="SinglePageDate"><FontAwesome name="clock-o"/> {this.props.currentObject.date}</div>
            <div className="SinglePageArticle">{this.props.currentObject.text}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Something is probably wrong with how you've architected things; you shouldn't need to re-render a parent component when a child renders. Or your refreshed page doesn't have the complete set of components to render.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using a router and you have a route for `Component1`(`ArticlesList`) and a different route for `Component2`(`Article`) so the problem would not be that you need to render `ArticleList` one more time,`ArticleList` does the job of getting the data for `Article` when you start navigating from first route but if you want your second route to also behave as a different page `Article` component should fetch its own data.

I would suggest adding passing a `fetchArticle` property to `Component2` that you can use in case there is no data loaded at the moment you try to render it. And also prevent rendering the article content until you receive the data for that article.

```
class Article extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { articleId, articleData, fetchArticle } = this.props;
    if (!articleData) {
        fetchArticle(articleId);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { articleData } = this.props;
    if (!articleData) {
      return (<div>Loading</div>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {articleData.content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Those are Lifecycle Methods, no? Sadly, i didn't study this, yet, and i don't know how to use them.

Comment: @ics I answered based on the interpretation of the question you posted but if you could provide more context about where your Component1 is getting its data would be better. I suggest you go through the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) to get more context about how components work.

Comment: As you can see above, in my component 2 take just current object, from an array of objects, as a props: this.props.currentObject and i use from the object just this.props.currentObject.title, date and text. Is a blog like app. Comp. 2 is rendered when i click on the article title, in the main page.I click de title, a new page is opened with entire article. 

Structure:

Main - > Articles (here is map function) -> Article (multiplyed by map)
 
Main -> SinglePageArticle (my above component) 

When i click on Article is linking me to SinglePageArticle, rendered by Main with route path.

Comment: @Ics I hope that you've already solved your problem by now, in case you haven't I'm willing to continue with the conversation and create codepens if we need to. What I am assuming is that your app is fetching data asynchronously from a server, and that the component that is triggering that action (fetch all articles)  is the Articles Component, the child Article then uses the data that was already available without need to do another fetch. If that's the case refreshing your app in the route that renders only the Main>Article components would result in not fetch and by consequence, no data.